# How to list all nvarchar in all tables in a SQL Server database with max length of each?

Tags: sql-server

I tried this:

```
select 
    TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
from 
    information_schema.columns 
where 
    data_type = 'nvarchar' 
    and (character_maximum_length = -1 or character_maximum_length = 3000)
order by 
    TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
```

but I also like to return, for each field, its max used length. How can I do it?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @Larnu because I want to resize all field from 3000 to 2000. But first I need to know if this will truncate some data, which, and how.

Comment: Considering that you probably don't have many columns that have a length of 3000, then it would seem the easiest thing to do would get the columns of that length (using a query like the above) and then querying them individually.

Comment: @Larnu I have 467 columns (in the whole DB)

Comment: You have 467 columns of that length? I would suggest the design phase had some problems then, if I am honest.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Move a copy of the db to a dev environment and run the column alter. You'll find out real quick which fail due to truncation.

Comment: @dfundako its 50gb of db, the machine don't have that space to replicate the whole

Comment: @markzzz that's because I was trying to find out what the *real* problem was, which is the design. That's fine, I now know that, but I do need to know the version.

Comment: @Larnu `Microsoft SQL Server 2016, 13.x`

Comment: OK, for `FOR XML PATH` it is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of dynamic SQL can achieve this. As you're on SQL Server 2016, then we need to use the old `FOR XML PATH` solution here, rather than the newer `STRING_AGG` function:

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = STUFF((SELECT @CRLF + N'UNION ALL' + @CRLF +
                         N'SELECT N' + QUOTENAME(s.[name],'''') + N' AS SchemaName,' + @CRLF +
                         N'       N' + QUOTENAME(t.[name],'''') + N' AS TableName,' + @CRLF +
                         N'       N' + QUOTENAME(c.[name],'''') + N' AS ColumnName,' + @CRLF +
                         N'       MAX(LEN(' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N')) AS MaxLength' + @CRLF +
                         N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.[name])
                  FROM sys.schemas s
                       JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
                       JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
                       JOIN sys.types ct ON c.system_type_id = ct.system_type_id
                  WHERE ct.[name] = N'nvarchar'
                    AND c.max_length IN (3000,-1)
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(MAX)') + N';',1,13,N'')

PRINT @SQL; --YOur debugging friend
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```